# Get a 25x2 array like the following (a sorted list with its coordinates)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

**My goal:** Get a 25x2 array like the following (a sorted list with its coordinates)

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 0
1 1
..
..
4 3
4 4
```

**My (failed) solution:**

```
import numpy as np
n=5
lis=np.zeros((n*n,2))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(i,j) # This prints just what I want to have in the array
        lis[j,0]=i
        lis[j,1]=j
```

**Output:**

```
array([[4., 0.],
       [4., 1.],
       [4., 2.],
       [4., 3.],
       [4., 4.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       ....
```

Comment: Hi MdF, welcome to SO, I can't figure out what is the sample data in this example, also could you please provide an example of the solution(It can be hand typed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row number is just `j`. It has to increment by 1 every iteration, even when `j` goes back to `0` on the next iteration of the `i` loop.

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        lis[i*n + j, 0] = i
        lis[i*n + j, 1] = j
```

Another way to do it is to loop in the range up to `n*n`, and then calculate the indices using division and remainder.

```
for i in range(n*n):
    lis[i, 0] = i // n
    lis[i, 1] = i % n
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Now it is crystal-clear. (I feel ashamed.)

Answer (score 0):

When you access `lis` by `lis[j,..]`, `j` ranges from 0 to 4, thus you never update rows after.

You have some options to achive your goal:

- Following your logic you can do:

  ```
  for i, e in enumerate(range(n*n)):
      lis[i] = e//n, e%n
  ```
- Using cartesian product:

  ```
  import itertools
  for i, e in enumerate(itertools.product(range(n), range(n))):
      lis[i] = e
  ```

Comment: Thanks FBruzzesi. Really useful.

Comment: This creates a list of tuples, not a numpy array.

Comment: Maybe something like `np.array(itertools.product(range(n), range(n)))`?

Comment: @Barmar is it possible that depends upon numpy version? in my local test I get a numpy ndarray of shape (25,2) as OP asked for.

Comment: I didn't realize that numpy would automatically spread the tuple to cells during the assignment, but it makes sense.